# Return from JS function in the chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this really simple function, which tries to lookup a value in the local storage:

```
function get_sectoken() {
    var sectoken;
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(obj) {
        if (obj.sectoken_val) {
            sectoken = obj.sectoken_val;
            console.log("Security token: " + sectoken);
        } else {
            console.log("Security token not found!");
        }
    });
    return sectoken;
}
```

If I try to assign it to a variable, I can see that `console.log()` has fired up:

```
st = get_sectoken();
Security token: UoMjWVeEeEqxeCKpRYaMmxIGAFyofEpC
```

But if I check what has been assigned to this variable, I see it's `undefined`:

```
st
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't make an asynchronous function synchronous.

Comment: OK, how can I improve my function and make it return values from the `storage.local`? Since values are stored locally (to my understanding on the machine, not synced to gdrive) asynchronous function is the last thing I need.

Comment: Doesn't look like Chrome provides a synchronous API. So the answer is: you can't.